# Data driven drop down menu Django

Tags: django, database

I am using a database "selectCountry" and I want to select all the country names in the database to get populated in the html dropdown menu.

Following is my code

```
   models.py

          class selectCountry(models.Model):
                 selectCountryoption = models.CharField(max_length = 30)


views.py
        def loadCountries(request):
         countries = selectCountry.objects.all()
         return render(request, 'register/bg-pages.html', {'countries': 
         countries})
```

html code

```
           <form action=".">
            <select name="Country" id="searchOption">
                <option value="">---------</option>
                {% for country in countries %}
                <option value="{{ countries.selectCountryoption }}">{{ 
                   countries.selectCountryoption }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"
         </form>
    </p>
```

The problem is the values are not getting populated in the list when I am requesting the page.

Comment: This is not how you write python code... please read & follow PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong value in your `for` loop.

```
<option value="{{ countries.selectCountryoption }}">{{ 
               countries.selectCountryoption }}</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="{{ country.selectCountryoption }}">{{ 
               country.selectCountryoption }}</option>
```

Comment: No, it is still not working. I changed the value and used as mentioned by you